# trouble making an "if" statment with time.now on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I'm trying to display a message depending on the time of the day and I currently have this piece of code:

```
<% if Time.now >= "7:00" and Time.now <= "14:00" %>
Good Morning <%= current_user.nome %>! <br>
<% else %>
Good Afternoon <%= current_user.nome %>!
<% end %>
```

It's currently 14:30 and the page still displays `Good Morning (username)`, when it should display `Good Evening (username)`

- Is my code wrong?
- How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you print the return of `Time.now`?

Comment: Can you compare a `String` with `Time`?

Comment: `2017-07-04 14:54:14 +0100 ` this is Time.Now

Comment: How do you compare `time` with `time` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
<% if Time.now >= Time.parse("7:00") and Time.now <= Time.parse("14:00") %>
  Good Morning <%= current_user.nome %>! <br>
<% else %>
  Good Afternoon <%= current_user.nome %>!
<% end %>
```

**Note:** `Time.now`  will return time object while `"7:00"` is a string, so you need to convert string time to time object and can compare.

Comment: Yep, this worked! Thanks, what was the problem with my code, can you explain why you use `Time.parse`?

Answer (score 2):

You can write like this Instead of Parsing the Time you can write simply

**Solution : 1**

```
<% if Time.now.hour >= 7 && Time.now.hour <= 14 %>
Good Morning <%= current_user.nome %>! <br>
<% else %>
Good Afternoon <%= current_user.nome %>!
<% end %>
```

**Solution : 2**

you can write less code via using ternary operator

```
(0..11).include?(Time.now.hour) ? "Good Morning <%= current_user.nome %>" : Good Afternoon <%= current_user.nome %>
```

Comment: if Time.now >= "7:00" -- You are checking against a string
Time.parse("7:00")   --- This will convert the String into Time format class

Comment: `14:30` would pass your `hour <= 14` check, but it should not.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is worth it to be a helper method:

```
# in app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def greeting(name)
  greeting = (7..13).cover?(Time.current.hour) ? 'Good Morning' : 'Good Afternoon'

  "#{greeting} #{name}".strip
end
```

And in your view:

```
<%= greeting(current_user.nome) %>!
```

Another more detailed version that supports uneven times might look like this:

```
def greeting(name)
  greeting = case Time.current.to_s(:time)
             when ('05:00'..'11:59') then 'Good Morning'
             when ('12:00'..'17:59') then 'Good Afternoon'
             when ('18:00'..'21:59') then 'Good Evening'
             else 'Good Night'
             end
  "#{greeting} #{name}".strip
end
```

Comment: Using 13 instead of 14 would be closer to the math specified. Or an extra period `(7...14)`

Comment: Another way: `Time.now.hour.between?(7,13)`

Comment: How would you handle a time frame like 6:30-13:30?

Comment: Nice, although I'd probably remove the `name` argument from the method and call it via `<%= greeting %> <%= current_user.nome %>!`

Comment: That is an option. But what happens when there is a user with a blank name?

Comment: Ideally, the user name should be required ;-). Of course you can handle it in the method, but it adds complexity and makes it a little less flexible. Without the `name` part, it would be a single `case` expression.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a helper:

```
def morning?(t = Time.current)
  t.between? t.change(hour: 7), t.change(hour: 14)
end
```

`t` is a time instance, defaulting to the current time, for example:

```
t = Time.current
#=> Tue, 04 Jul 2017 16:30:09 CEST +02:00
```

[`change`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-change) sets one or more of the time's elements. If only `:hour` is specified, the "smaller" units like minutes and seconds are set to 0:

```
t.change(hour: 7)  #=> Tue, 04 Jul 2017 07:00:00 CEST +02:00
t.change(hour: 14) #=> Tue, 04 Jul 2017 14:00:00 CEST +02:00
```

`between?` finally checks if `t` is between these values.

Passing the current time as an argument makes it easier to test the method:

```
morning? Time.parse('06:59') #=> false
morning? Time.parse('07:00') #=> true
morning? Time.parse('14:00') #=> true
morning? Time.parse('14:01') #=> false
```

Usage:

```
<% if morning? %>
  Good Morning <%= current_user.nome %>!
<% else %>
  Good Afternoon <%= current_user.nome %>!
<% end %>
```

Comment: I dont see the need for `helpers` since I only need this on the index view, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I would use helpers to store methods and keep views plain.

```
class ApplicationHelper
  def greeting
    "Good #{time_greeting} #{current_user.nome}"
  end

  def time_greeting
    return "Morning" if Time.now.hour.between?(7, 13)
    "Afternoon"
  end
end
```

Then you may only use greeting method in your views:

```
<%= greeting %>
```